# What's the deal with Whirlpool "Better than Inverter" refrigerators?

Tags: refrigerator

I've been looking around for a new refrigerator and one thing that stands out to me among the current lineup is that Whirlpool seems to be the only one not coming up with an inverter fridge. Instead they market their conventional fridges as "better than inverter." They supposedly cool faster and are even more energy efficient, and they actually have some measurements from a third party power lab to back up their energy efficiency claim.

Can anyone shed more light on the details behind the marketing hype? Surely there must be some drawback, or everyone else would be doing the same thing?

Comment: Probably just marketing hype. A third party lab being paid by them is going to have a strong incentive to come up with a way to spin the measurements to get the result they want. Lacking several refrigerators to test under a regimen I come up with, I'll be suspicious of the "third party result" given wide benefit from inverters in A/C where there's standardized testing that's published.

Comment: "cools faster" is pure marketing BS. Unless you are in the habit of shutting the fridge off or leaving the door open for extended times, who cares how "fast" it cools?